# How to monitor a specific pod if it goes in non running state

Tags: kubernetes, openshift, prometheus, promql, prometheus-alertmanager

I need a help to monitor a specific pod

monitoring all the pods in the namespace using this below expression, but the problem is it is throwing the alerts for regular jobs as well, Need help to monitor specific pod

```
 expr: min_over_time(sum by (namespace, pod) (kube_pod_status_phase{phase=~"Pending|Unknown|Failed"})[15m:1m]) > 0
```

Comment: what do you mean by regular? a job also create pod which is expected

Comment: yes job creates the pods